# Multiple custom cells with multiple UIButtons crash

Tags: uitableview, uibutton, exc-bad-access, custom-cell

I have searched for this question and there is a huge amount of stuff related, but nothing is similar to my problem.

I have a UITableView with 2 different custom cells (I choose to do custom cells because my design of the cells is drastically different from the standard ones), each having several things, specifically 2 UIButtons.

I cannot get those Buttons to work, when I assign the selector to a simple

```
-(IBAction)action { NSLog(@"test"); }
```

or every variant/similar ways

```
-(IBAction)action:(id)sender { NSLog(@"test"); }
-(void)action { NSLog(@"test"); }
-(void)action:(id)sender { NSLog(@"test"); }
```

I get a crash with the annoying: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

This error usually means that I am trying to access something that has been released, or something that it cannot figure out is. So I thought maybe it couldn't figure out what cell I was calling it from, because there are several cells of each type. So I tried to save the cells so I basically had a few cells called cell1, cell2, etc declared in my .h and that way I would never release them unless I quit the app, but I still get the error...

Where could the error be!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As I could not find a good way to do this I just "emulated" in a way the behavior of a table.
So I added 4 views on the page and made x number of them appear according to my needs... was a real pain and looks ugly having 50+ IBOutlets for each views' fields but works...

If anybody gets this to work with tables please let me know!
Thanks